# Should I only get unsolved street crimes in Free Play?

Tags: la-noire

I'm currently on the Homicide desk but have returned to Traffic in free play mode in order to finish all the street crimes.

However, I'm still being given street crimes that I definitely remember solving. I thought the game would know which crimes you've solved and give you new ones - forcing me to replay things doesn't make sense. Is this meant to happen?

I usually solved the cases with liberal application of bullets, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dispatcher will give them to you (I believe) randomly, so you will be asked to return and replay crimes that you've already solved.  There's no benefit to doing so, however.

Although sometimes you can fail a street crime, you'll be told you've failed and given the option to retry it.  It does not matter (in most cases) if you kill the perp or capture them.  In fact, in most cases killing them is the only option.

Comment: The dispatcher does indeed give you previously-solved crimes. In free play mode they're all on the map though.