# How can I tell which street crimes I have solved?

Tags: la-noire

Related to my [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/47896/8090) about street crimes in Free Play mode - how can I see my progress on street crimes for each desk? I couldn't see anything in the Free Play menu when I chose a desk, and the in-game statistics just show a total out of 40.

I was wondering if there was a way to double-check that I was indeed being given the same street crimes a second times, rather than, say, a bug/other issue where my progress wasn't saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can tell from the case selection screen, but when you're in Free Play mode, you can check the map.  Street crimes you've solved are shown as gray icons (I believe they look like a person walking) on the map.  If all you see is gray icons, you've done all the street crimes for that desk.

If you see one you haven't done, you can set it as your waypoint, and then you'll get that crime immediately - without having to wait for the dispatcher to work its way around to that one.  This really helps if there's just one or two crimes left to go on a desk, or if there's a set of them close together that you'd like to tackle as a group.

[This guide](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=311062) seems to back me up, and also makes note of a couple of other caveats:

> How do you know which ones you have completed?
>
> The ones you've completed show up as grey on the map and the ones you havent will be red. Free roam shows all available street crimes at that time frame [whereas] in-story only shows when [you're] in the vicinity.

Comment: As far as I can remember, the little running man icons don't show up on the map until central dispatch calls you about them. So this would probably work for crimes you've already been called about, but not the rest. I will double-check my map, though.

Comment: I feel like when I went back to the "free play" map, I could see *all* of the crimes, even ones that I'd never gotten a call about.  I don't have my copy handy to check at this point, though.

Comment: I also had [Rockstar Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/) interaction turned on (which I highly recommend if you're going for 100% completion in this game), which may have been a factor.

Comment: You're right - I checked my map and there were a bunch of icons there.